# Named variables in math

Tags: notation, index-notation

In my publication I have a case where it is a bit difficult to keep track of indices / variables, because of I have multiple of them and some are replaced with actual integers. Let me give an example:

Fully written, I have

$x_{i,t}$

but since I would need to put an $i$ into the index of nearly every symbol, it is much more elegant to refrain to do so and just write

$x_{t}$

However, now I have the case that $t$ is indeed 1, not just any integer, *and* that in this particular formula I need to bring back the $i$. How can I make this clear? I would like to write use named variables (similar as I am used from programming), so along the lines

$x_{i,t=1} = \ldots$

Is this valid notation? Is there a better, concise alternative?

Also, how about if this issue does not arise for index notation, but in the parenthesis:

$y(j=2,s=4)$

instead of

$y(2,4)$

Is this valid notation?

Comment: Is $x$ the only symbol that has subscripts? If not, are there other symbols that have just one subscript?

Comment: @BarryCipra: $x$ is not the only symbol. Many symbols have all kinds of subscripts. Mostly one subscripts, but also two and three (although I try to get rid of the three subscripts my e.g. removing $i$ at most places).

Comment: In that case I'd say it's a question of how easy is it for a reader to keep track of how many subscripts each symbol "really" has, and which subscripts are being suppressed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to mantain the $x_{i,t}$ notation. If you have to explicitly write some value for $t=1$, just write
$$
x_{i,1} = \dots
$$
Similarly, for $i=3$ then
$$
x_{3,t} = \dots
$$

Sometimes (such as in case of iteration numbers) it is also useful to use apexes and parenthesis:
$$
x^{(k)}_{i,t} = \dots
$$

In these cases, I always use parenthesis in order to distinguish it from squared, cubic, $\dots$ values:
$$
x^2_{i,t} = x_{i,t}\,x_{i,t}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to be lazy and to keep the $i$ subscript even though it is repeated. As you can see from your own examples, any other approach is horrible.

Comment: It is not about being lazy - just one click in LaTeX makros. It is about readability which has been criticized by reviewers before. (And looking back they might have been right.)

Comment: @Make42: If you can't see that your proposed alternatives are horrible, then I'm not surprised that reviewers have criticised your readability! Rule number 1: Keep It Simple.

Comment: :-D, harsh, but fair enough.  There is only one or two formulas where I have the mentioned issue. Having a ton of $i$-indices everywhere that are not necessary and make readability difficult is also not "keeping it simple".

Comment: @Make42: Yes it is.

Comment: Ok. Well, maybe it is just me thinking [named variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter) are a good idea.